# How to get published version of site pages in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, caml-query, sitepages

Is there any way to get the all site pages last published version using rest api camlquery.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

See: [How to fetch only Site Pages and not page templates from Site Pages library using REST call?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/295518/how-to-fetch-only-site-pages-and-not-page-templates-from-site-pages-library-usin)

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Site Pages')/items?$select=Title,FileLeafRef,Modified,OData__ModerationStatus&$filter=OData__ModerationStatus eq 0
```

This will return all the site pages that are published (`OData__ModerationStatus eq 0` indicates the page is published). The `Modified` field can be used to determine when the page was last published.